# matching lists in syntax-parse

Tags: racket

how can I match a list in syntax parse? I tried this code:

```
(syntax-parse #'(1 2)
  [(list a b) (printf "a: ~a~n") #'a])
```

but doesn't seem to work. I'm assuming `'(1 2)` is a list in racket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern syntax of `syntax-parse` and `match` are different.

Try:

```
(syntax-parse #'(1 2)
    [(a b) (printf "a: ~a~n" #'a)])
```